# Adding custom OnTextChange event handler on custom TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I currently have a custom text box, it implements majority of the base implementations a normal text box has, by doing something like:

```
    public string Text
    {
        get { return customTextBox.Text; }
        set { customTextBox.Text = value; }
    }
```

I now want to implement a custom event handler to get a postback on text changed. I currently am doing the following is this correct if not then how should I go about this:

```
    private static readonly object EventCustomTextChanged = new Object();

    public event EventHandler TextChanged
    {
        add
        {
            Events.AddHandler(EventCustomTextChanged, value);
        }
        remove
        {
            Events.RemoveHandler(EventCustomTextChanged, value);
        }
    }
```

This implementation comes from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.ontextchanged.aspx

Before someone says why don't you use the one thats already there, I will tell you it's not implented because this is a custom user control. I am trying to implement it.

Thanks in Advanced!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the way to do it:

```
public event EventHandler TextChanged
{
    add { customTextBox.TextChanged += value; }
    remove { customTextBox.TextChanged -= value; }
}
```

Assuming that `customTextBox` is the `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox` control.

Comment: +1, but there can be one issue - if user control code manipulates the text property internally, it will raise text changed event which may not be desired sometimes.

Comment: True, that's what I often hate about events raised by property setters.

Comment: yeah the control doesn't maniuplate text property thankfully, currently away from dev desk will try this when I get back.