# Exposing and then using OnTextChange Event handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, user-controls

Related Question: [Adding custom OnTextChange event handler on custom TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580987/adding-custom-ontextchange-event-handler-on-custom-textbox)

In the related question I asked how I could expose OnTextChange in my custom textbox control and we resolved it by:

```
public event EventHandler TextChanged
{
    add { customTextBox.TextChanged += value; }
    remove { customTextBox.TextChanged -= value; }
}
```

I am trying use TextChanged event like this when the control is implemented:

```
    <uc:CustomTextBox ID="customTextBox"
                      runat="server"
                      OnTextChanged="CustomTextBox_OnTextChanged">
    </uc:CustomTextBox>
```

This never seems to hit the following when running:

```
    protected void CustomTextBox_OnTextChanged(System.EventArgs e)
    {
     // Do something here
    }
```

Or hit:

```
    protected void CustomTextBox_OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     // Do something here
    }
```

What am I doing wrong, what am I missing out and is this the best way or common practice way to do everything I am trying to do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `AutoPostBack=True` property of TextBox.

If you are designing a web user control then simply define public property to set `True/False` value of  `CustomTextBox` in user control's code-behind:

```
public   bool AutoPostBack
    {
        get
        {
            return CustomTextBox.AutoPostBack;
        }
        set
        {
            CustomTextbox.AutoPostBack = value;
        }
    }
```

If you are developing a custom web control then you can to override the `AutoPostBack` property for the customization. If you don't want to customize `AutoPostBack` property then don't override it.

In case you override AutoPostBack property, please invoke the super class's default implementation.

```
public override  bool AutoPostBack
    {
        get
        {
            return base.AutoPostBack;
        }
        set
        {
            base.AutoPostBack = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I did the following: `public virtual bool AutoPostBack{ get; set; }` and then I added the line `AutoPostBack="true"` to the control and I am still having no success.

Comment: Sorry mate thanks attempting but it doesn't seem to work. The first one bubbles up and then when set to true doesn't work. The override returns `base does not have AutopostBack.`

Comment: Is this a user control or a custom server control? If it's a user control, create an `AutoPostBack` property in the user control, and use the property to get and set `customTextBox.AutoPostBack` property.

Comment: it's a custom server control.

Comment: It works, I wasn't defining OnTextChanged="CustomTextBox_OnTextChanged" on the server control just on each child instance. Works now thanks buddy :).

Answer (score 0):

In order for `OnTextChanged` to fire, you need to specify `AutoPostBack="true"` on the TextBox.

In the ASPX markup:

```
<uc:CustomTextBox ID="customTextBox" runat="server" OnTextChanged="CustomTextBox_OnTextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></uc:CustomTextBox>
```

In the code-behind of the CustomTextBox user control:

```
public bool AutoPostBack 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        //the textbox in the user control
        return customTextBox.AutoPostBack; 
    } 
    set 
    { 
        customTextBox.AutoPostBack = value; 
    } 
}
```