# OnTextChange Partial Postback not occurring

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have the following code for an OnTextChanged event:

```
protected void CustomTextBox_OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tick.Attributes["class"] == "tick displayBlock")
    {
        tick.Attributes["class"] = "displayNone";
        tick.Attributes.Add("class", "displayNone");
    }
    checkAvailability.Attributes.Add("class", "displayBlock");
    checkAvailability.Attributes["class"] = "displayBlock";
}
```

And:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMyUpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <uc:CustomTextBox ID="txtUserName"
            OnTextChanged="CustomTextBox_OnTextChanged" 
            AutoPostBack="True"
            class="someClass">
        </uc:CustomTextBox> 
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

So I have the above code works perfectly fine in Chrome, IE 8, 9.

However Firefox 6 doesn't seem to do a partial postback.

Before anyone asks I have bubbled up events ontextchanges and autopostback to be used by my customtextbox instances. You can see how on related question: [Exposing and then using OnTextChange Event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596050/exposing-and-then-using-ontextchange-event-handler/7599307#7599307)

Comment: You write: **partial postback**. However I don't see you mention AJAX in your question.
So, do you use AJAX? If so, post the code please.

Comment: @MichelvanEngelen I have added the UpdatePanel allowing me to do the ajax.

Comment: Ahh got it, CustomTextBox_OnTextChanged is a custom server control I have created, the parent control had AutoPostBack = "true" and the child control instance also have AutoPostBack = "true" making the ontextchanged execute twice removed it from the parent and it works now. SIGH* if someone wants bounty points you can post the answer I am feeling generous!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was being cause by a double AutoPostBack.

Parent control:

```
<uc:CustomTextBox ID="ctbMyTextBox"
                        OnTextChanged="CustomTextBox_OnTextChanged"              
                        AutoPostBack="True"             
                        class="someClass">         
</uc:CustomTextBox>
```

Child Control:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMyUpdatePanel" runat="server">     
    <ContentTemplate>            
        <uc:CustomTextBoxChild ID="ctbcMyTextBox"
                          OnTextChanged="CustomTextBox_OnTextChanged"              
                          AutoPostBack="True"             
                          class="someClass">         
        </uc:CustomTextBoxChild>      
    </ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In the parent control I removed `AutoPostBack="True"` and this fixed the issue for me.

If someone can give further explanation as to why a Double AutoPostback can cause this I would be happy to check your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the autopostback from the parent and add it to child(your custom one). That will solve the issue. Further, since its  a custom control so you are inheriting the properties from your parent. Even if you remove the Autopostback from the custo control, i think it might work as the property is true in its parent, by default.

Answer (score 0):

set `UpdatePanel Mode="Conditional"` and 
 `AutoPostBack="True" and enableviewstate="true"`

now it will work