# Issue related to Firing TextChanged event in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer

i have asp.net webapplication. i have following control in .aspx Page

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtZip" runat="server" CssClass="span1" OnTextChanged="txtZip_TextChanged"
                                                        MaxLength="5" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

It works well in IE9 and IE10, but it doesn't work in IE11 and IE12

TextChanged evnt is not firing in IE11 and IE12. how to fire it??

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [OnTextChange Partial Postback not occuring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612858/ontextchange-partial-postback-not-occuring)